# How to get the current date and time in textbox in IST ( Indian Standard Time) in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to get the current date and time in textbox in IST ( Indian Standard Time) in vb.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
        Dim UTCTime As DateTime = Date.UtcNow
        Dim IndianTime As DateTime = UTCTime.AddHours(5.5)
        Response.Write(IndianTime)
```

This will give you the current IST from any server world wide (as long as it's time is correct)